# Why does accessing a Groovy process's getText() twice cause a failure?

Tags: groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running some curl code with a Gradle task and I noticed that if I access the process's text twice, then the second access always fails. I noticed that by passing process.text to XlmSlurper(). If I first printlned process.text it would crash at the slurped, if I didn't println it then the slurped worked.
Here's some code that illustrates this behavior. First is a version of a task that fails:

```
    task hello {
        println "****** HELLO ******"

        def process = ['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-H', 'Accept: Application/xml', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json', "http://itemid.sea.redacted.com/item_ids", '-d', '{"user":"Y2VxYnVpbGRhZ2VudDpCdTFsZCE=","request":"guid"}'].execute()
        process.waitFor()

        println "err.text"
        println process.err.text

        println "process.text 1 is:"
        println process.text

        println "process.text 2 is:"
        println process.text
    }
```

When this is executed the output is:

```
****** HELLO ******
err.text
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   141    0    85  100    56   2412   1589 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2428

process.text 1 is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><long xmlns="http://redacted.com/">121144</long>
process.text 2 is:
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:80)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:462)
```

But if the last two println lines are commented out then it is successful:

```
    task hello {
        println "****** HELLO ******"

        def process = ['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-H', 'Accept: Application/xml', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json', "http://itemid.sea.redacted.com/item_ids", '-d', '{"user":"Y2VxYnVpbGRhZ2VudDpCdTFsZCE=","request":"guid"}'].execute()
        process.waitFor()

        println "err.text"
        println process.err.text

        println "process.text 1 is:"
        println process.text

      //  println "process.text 2 is:"
      //  println process.text
    }
```

Which has output:

```
****** HELLO ******
err.text
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   141    0    85  100    56   1977   1303 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2023

process.text 1 is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><long xmlns="http://redacted.com/">121145</long>
:help

Welcome to Gradle 2.2.1.

To run a build, run gradlew <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradlew tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradlew --help

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Why is the addition/removal of those last printlns causing such a difference?

(Also why is there :help ... in the output of the second version?)

In both cases I'm running from the command line using ./gradlew

Its the same problem if getText() is used instead of text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting a stream back which can only be read once.  Write it out to a file or variable & then read it as many times as you want from that file/variable.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of this function says :

> **public static String getText(Process self) throws IOException**
>
> Read the text of the output stream of the Process. Closes all the
>   streams associated with the process after retrieving the text.

the standard output is read until EOF, then returned as a String. The value is not cached, a second invocation reach a closed stream, and fail.

Moreover, in groovy, `process.getText()` is equivalent to `process.text`